# Python-OpenCV cv2 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to create an image in python using openCV. I make a list of lists, each list having 16 numbers, from 0 to 255 (16 lists). Then I convert the big list in a numpy ndarray, and try to write that into an image using cv2.imwrite(). This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

colours = []
numbers = []
a=0
for i in range(256):
    numbers.append(a)
    a+=1

for x in range(16):
    new_list = [numbers[16*x:16*x+16]]
    colours.append(new_list)

col = np.asarray(colours)
new_image = cv2.imwrite("rainbow.png",col)
```

It runs well until the last line. Then it gives me this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (image.channels() == 1 || image.channels() == 3 || image.channels() == 4) in cv::imwrite_, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp, line 600
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kormou.py", line 16, in <module>
    new_image = cv2.imwrite("rainbow.png",col)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:600: error: (-215) image.channels() == 1 || image.channels() == 3 || image.channels() == 4 in function cv::imwrite_
```

In generally I'm a beginner so it may be something very obvious which I'm missing but I haven't been able to find similar error question here.

Comment: It's saying that the assertion that "image.channels() == 1 || image.channels() == 3 || image.channels() == 4" has failed in the imwrite function. So, how many channels does the image have?

Comment: You're feeding a 16 channel "image" to [`imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite). As the docs state, it only supports 1,3 or 4 channels. Also, it doesn't return an image, but a boolean, so the variable name `new_image` is rather misleading.

Answer (score 3):

There is this very minute mistake you are doing. Figure out from the following working code -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

colours = []
numbers = []
a=0
for i in range(256):
    numbers.append(a)
    a+=1

for x in range(16):
    new_list = numbers[16*x:16*x+16]
    colours.append(new_list)

print colours
col = np.asarray(colours)
new_image_flag = cv2.imwrite("rain.png",col)
```

Check edit for hint.